# How do I use "reverse" or an equivalent to refer to urls that are hooked into DjangoCMS?

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm using DjangoCMS with app integration, like documented here:

http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-cms/en/latest/extending_cms/app_integration.html

This, however, means that my app's urls in no longer referred to in the global `urls.py`.

Now, if I try to use a `reverse` on one of the urls of my app this fails. This kind of makes sense, since the urls of my app are no longer in my `urls.py`. However, even though it makes sense, it's very annoying.

Weirdly enough, the `{% url %}` decorator *does* still work. Any idea on how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URLs can be reversed on apphooked apps, as long as the apphook is hooked on a page in all languages and the server is restarted after it has been hooked.

In some cases there has been issues with the reverse function, prefixing the URL name with the language namespace should fix that. Eg: `reverse('de:myview')` as opposed to just `reverse('myview')`. This does not apply to the `{% url %}` tag.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I ran into one of the "as long as" conditions (probably: not hooked in all languages), and simply did not try it again.